Replacement oscillator for SI4703
The SI4703 requires a 32.876 kHz crystal with 22pF load capacitors. One specifically manufactured by Epson as per the datasheet. Evidently this part isn't available as I've checked Mouser, Digikey and LCSC which do not have any. Is there a known replacement crystal for this chip? If not, how is a good replacement determined? I know other 32.876 kHz crystals are available but not with that load capacitance. Explanations appreciated.

here is one has a stock of 1070

also on digikey and mouser

this has a load capacitance of 12.5p. Since the datasheet clearly and deliberately mentioned the Epson I assume that the load capacitance matters. 22p to 12.5 pF is a big difference. Is it that this difference doesnt matter?

22pF load capacitors mean the crystal sees a load capacitance of around 14pF depending on the chip and layout (they are effectively in series plus the stray and input capacitances). You should do the calculation or pick a crystal that matches the load capacitance of the recommended crystal and use the same capacitors they recommend.

It does not specify any specific crystal. There is no specific part number.
You only know the crystal is from FC-135 series made by Epson and made to run at 32768 Hz frequency.
The data sheet for the whole series defines some parameters for the crystal has and with what options it could be bought.
This helps to find a suitable crystal from other manufacturers.
The chip datasheet explains that 7pF to 22pF capacitors can be used, and that the examples use 22 pF capacitors.
This means that the crystal must have at least 11pF load capacitance rating when other pin and stray capacitances are ignored.
